# QGIS 3 - Python script running from toolbox

Tags: python, qgis-3, toolbox

I've wrote a Python script to delete geometries inside multiple layers.
When I try to run it with double click from models or from scripts it's not running. No error.
[image]

But if I edit the script and run it from Edit window it is working
[image]

I don't understand why.

EDIT 1 : CODE

```
#model test
```

#modelname aa
from qgis.core import *

class StergeGeometrii(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):

```
if(len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Planse'))!=0):
    layers_planse = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Planse')
    layer = layers_planse[0]
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    feats = layer.getFeatures()
    dfeats = []
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures:
        for feat in feats:
            dfeats.append(feat.id())
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(dfeats)

if(len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Limita Constructii'))!=0):    
    layers_constructii = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Limita Constructii')
    layer = layers_constructii[0]
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    feats = layer.getFeatures()
    dfeats = []
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures:
        for feat in feats:
            dfeats.append(feat.id())
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(dfeats)

if(len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Limita Imobile'))!=0):    
    layers_imobile= QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Limita Imobile')
    layer = layers_imobile[0]
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    feats = layer.getFeatures()
    dfeats = []
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures:
        for feat in feats:
            dfeats.append(feat.id())
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(dfeats)

if(len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Limita Tarla'))!=0):   
    layers_tarla= QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Limita Tarla')
    layer = layers_tarla[0]
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    feats = layer.getFeatures()
    dfeats = []
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures:
        for feat in feats:
            dfeats.append(feat.id())
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(dfeats)
    
if(len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Limita Sector'))!=0):
    layers_sector= QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Limita Sector')
    layer = layers_sector[0]
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    feats = layer.getFeatures()
    dfeats = []
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures:
        for feat in feats:
            dfeats.append(feat.id())
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(dfeats)
        
if(len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Numere Postale'))!=0):
    layers_nr_postal= QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Numere Postale')
    layer = layers_nr_postal[0]
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    feats = layer.getFeatures()
    dfeats = []
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures:
        for feat in feats:
            dfeats.append(feat.id())
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(dfeats)
else:
    print("numere postale nu exista")
 
if(len(QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Toponimie'))!=0):
    layers_toponimie= QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Toponimie')
    layer = layers_toponimie[0]
    caps = layer.dataProvider().capabilities()
    feats = layer.getFeatures()
    dfeats = []
    if caps & QgsVectorDataProvider.DeleteFeatures:
        for feat in feats:
            dfeats.append(feat.id())
        res = layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(dfeats)
        

def name(self):
    return 'Sterge_Geometrii'

def displayName(self):
    return 'Sterge_Geometrii'

def group(self):
    return 'Sectorial'

def groupId(self):
    return 'Sectorial'
```

Comment: Please include code as formatted text, rather than a screenshot. It is much easier to debug and will appear in searches etc.

Comment: Your code must be inside a function of the class